# Can't install pip on python 2.7, only python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation

I have been trying to install pip for python 2.7, but I am unable to. I want pip to work for both python 2.7 and python 3. Here is a summary of what I have done so far:

```
python -V
Python 2.7.15

echo $PATH
... /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin ...
```

I've also done a few checks to know where everything is (I have two '/usr/local/bin/python'). I believe there should only be one?

```
which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

which python
/usr/local/bin/python

ls -l $(which python)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 XXXXX  admin  36 May 24 14:28 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python
```

When I do:

```
brew list python | grep pip
```

I only get results for python3, nothing at all for python2

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/pip3
```

Things I have tried that do not work, include:

```
python get-pip.py
"can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

brew install pip
"Error: No available formula with the name "pip" "
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To download get_pip.py file run

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then try

```
python get-pip.py
```

Docs here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: This script does not work on Python 2.7 As of 2022, the minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using linux Ubuntu and could solve my Pip/Python environment following this steps:

Restore PYTHON 3:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 --version
```

if necessary...

```
sudo python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Restore PYTHON 2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
pip --version
```

if necessary...

```
sudo python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3
```

In my case the last command was the one that make the big trick I was missing. Moreover the version 9.0.3 is the last version works for me.

Comment: @is there a yum version of the force installing pip on python2.7?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on a Mac. Since you have Python installed, that means you have `easy_install` as well.

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: Hi Moss, thanks for your answer. However, after running this, it did not solve my problem. "python2 -m pip --version" resulted in 
"/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip"

Comment: Not sure if we are talking about the same answer here.

Comment: Hi Rushil. 'sudo easy_install pip' executed without an error, but when I looked for 'python2 -m pip --version' I got an error. The answer above allowed me to execute the latter command without an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pip is not compatible with python 2.7
So you can use higher version of python. For me 2.7.18 works well.
Then you can run python get-pip.py to install pip