# how to install pip for python 2.7?

Tags: python, pip, centos

I followed the link @https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/#2-install-pip to install pip ,however its intalled for python 2.6 that comes with the system,how do I install it for python 2.7?

```
sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package epel-release-6-8.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Installing pip

```
 sudo yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package python-pip-7.1.0-1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

pip version

```
pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Machine configuration:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: OracleServer
Description:    Oracle Linux Server release 6.6
Release:    6.6
Codename:   n/a
```

/usr/local

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pip on python 2.7, only python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805485/cant-install-pip-on-python-2-7-only-python-3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+pip+Python+2.7

Comment: None of the above solved my problems...like I said  am usine OracleServer 6.6

Comment: The accepted answer there works everywhere, Linux, w32, MacOS…

Comment: @phd That gave me an error 
`$ python get-pip.py 
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
..
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+configured+with+locations+that+require+TLS%2FSSL%2C+however+the+ssl+module+in+Python+is+not+available

Comment: I couldnt find anything that works for python 2.7,I am still stuck at the same error,I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available , I tried `yum install openssl-devel -y`  but I couldnt find any sources to hack as mentioned in the second solution in the link I shared

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might want to try [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 25):

Try installing manually:

```
wget -P ~/.local/lib https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
python2.7 ~/.local/lib/get-pip.py --user 
#if using bash
printf "\nPATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This fails at step2 with error `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip`

Comment: how to get rid of this SSL error?this has been the blocker for me

Comment: Did you compile python yourself? Have you got OpenSSL? See fx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available/46087798#46087798

Comment: No,I didn't compile python myself...I don't  seem to able to find the python source under `/usr/local` ,how to I find the source?

Comment: I added a screen shot of how my `/usr/local` looks

Comment: Try installing OpenSSL: ‘yum install openssl’

Comment: ‘yum install openssl’ throws the output `Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package openssl-1.0.1e-57.0.6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: Strange, did you install python 2.7 from epel, with yum?

Comment: It was already present on the machine am using, so am not sure how it was installed,anyway to recover from this situation?

Comment: Python 2 will soon be End of life, can you use python 3? yum install python3. If not, yum install python2.7 to make sure it’s all there?

Comment: yum list python*

Comment: has been updated to: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py.  The url in your post will now only work with Python3

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Ubuntu such as 20.04, python-pip is no longer a package. Therefore, the old:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Will fail.

Here's how to work around this issue:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Link: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/

Answer (score 0):

pip has dropped a support to python 2.7. If you still want to use it for python 2.7, downgrading the pip will help you:

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pip` for python 2.7 by running the followings on you terminal:

```bash
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
python2 -m ensurepip --default-pip
python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
python2 -m pip install termcolor   # (termcolor is the module I want to install for python2)
```

Answer (score -3):

Just go into terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

I know that this at least works on a raspberry pi.